# CTL and the modal mu-calculus

Tags: logic, temporal-logic, mu-calculus

Is there any literature / results to which fragment of the modal mu-calculus the logic CTL corresponds? I know that in order to tranlsate the until operators of CTL, it suffices to use a single mu-operator. Does this imply that CTL coincides with the fragment of the mu-calculus containing those formulas that are built without using nu-operators?

Comment: Yes, check out [Bradfield and Stirling's Modal Mu-Calculi](https://www.julianbradfield.org/Research/MLH-bradstir.pdf).  They go into great details on this.